# how to pass list records to many2many field?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, odoo

i need to get the range between 2 years on a many2many field each year must be a record on the model

i added 2 fields to get the 2 years and and method to get the range between them

```
class yearrange(models.Model):
_name = 'yearrange'
_rec_name = 'name'

name = fields.Char()

 class autopart(models.Model):
_inherit = 'product.template'

@api.multi
@api.depends('start', 'end')
def years(self):
    record = [int(x) for x in range(int(self.start), int(self.end))]
    for rec in self:
        rec.rang=record

start = fields.Char(string="", required=False, )
end = fields.Char(string="", required=False, )
rang = fields.Many2many(comodel_name="yearrange", string="",compute=years )
```

if i add any data to the field of years i get this error 
Missing record
Record does not exist or has been deleted.

(Records: [2010, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020], User: 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i did it by this way :

```
class yearrange(models.Model):
_name = 'yearrange'
_rec_name = 'name'

name = fields.Char()
product_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="product.template")


 class autopart(models.Model):
_inherit = 'product.template'

@api.multi
@api.onchange('start', 'end')
def years(self):
    print('innnnn')
    for rec in self:
        if rec.start and rec.end:
            record = [int(x) for x in range(int(rec.start)+1, int(rec.end)+1)]
            list = []
            for item in record:
                print(item)
                range_id = self.env['yearrange'].create({
                    'name': str(item)
                })
                list.append(range_id.id)
            rec.rang = [(4, x, None) for x in list]

start = fields.Char(string="", required=False, )
end = fields.Char(string="", required=False, )
rang = fields.One2many(comodel_name="yearrange", inverse_name="product_id", store=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update your compute method like this:

```
@api.multi
@api.depends('start', 'end')
def years(self):
    for rec in self:
        rec.rang = [(0, 0, {'name': x}) for x in range(int(rec.start), int(rec.end) + 1)]
```

Comment: Thanks dear for your help i appreciate that too much
but it's still not working for me when i enter data into start and end field i get records in the rage field but it's still = False aslo just i press save all records disappeared

Comment: it's print 
yearrange(<odoo.models.NewId object at 0x7f526dc41978>, ......... 
in log

Answer (score 1):

In Odoo, at the time of creating a record, you can pass values to its child be it a One2Many or Many2Many by using its semantics, here [(0,0,{})] represents am trying to create new One2Many record.

Note:

In valsB, I have appended the values of ClassC, and this dict am appending the original Vals of Class A, which will be like passing nested dict of values into ClassA

Similarly there exists a semantics for editing/updating, deleting and so, please refer the below samples which are used for both One2Many & Many2Many.

(0, 0, { values }) link to a new record that needs to be created with the given values dictionary

(1, ID, { values }) update the linked record with id = ID (write values on it)

(2, ID) remove and delete the linked record with id = ID (calls unlink on ID, that will delete the object completely, and the link to it as well)

(3, ID) cut the link to the linked record with id = ID (delete the relationship between the two objects but does not delete the target object itself)

(4, ID) link to existing record with id = ID (adds a relationship)

(5) unlink all (like using (3,ID) for all linked records)

(6, 0, [IDs]) replace the list of linked IDs (like using (5) then (4,ID) for each ID in the list of IDs)